# Changing xml content when converting it to HTML via xslt

Tags: java, xslt

I need to transform a XML file to HTML format via XSLT and java. One of the tags contains the link of intranet page like:

http://mycompany.com&mypage=xyz&version=999

now I want to use this value in href attribute in generated html.

Before using this value I want to get rid of "amp;" and change the url like appending it with username.

Can I do it via some XSLT function or I have to replace it in java code ?

Answer (score 2):

> Can I do it via some XSLT function or I have to replace it in java
>   code ?

This is trivial in XSLT.

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:param name="pUserName" select="'someUser'"/>

 <xsl:template match="someLink">
     <a href="{substring-before(., '?')}/{$pUserName}">someLink</a>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on this XML document**:

```
<someLink>http://mycompany.com?mypage='xyz'&amp;version='999'</someLink>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<a href="http://mycompany.com/someUser">someLink</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try it and let you know. Also can I give userName dynamically via some system properties ?

Comment: @KshitijGupta: Most probably this can be done -- how to pass external parameters to the XSLT transformation is implementation (vendor) dependent. Read the documentation of the XSLT processor that you are using and there must exist a section on this topic. If you can't find this information, ask a new question and someone would probably share how this should be done.

Answer (score 1):

try fn:replace(string,pattern,replace)  and fn:concat(string,string,...)

Returns a string that is created by replacing the given pattern with the replace argument
Example: replace("Bella Italia", "l", "*")
Result: 'Be**a Ita*ia'

Example: replace("Bella Italia", "l", "")
Result: 'Bea Itaia'

fn:concat(string,string,...)    Returns the concatenation of the strings
Example: concat('XPath ','is ','FUN!')
Result: 'XPath is FUN!'

Ref: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp

Note: Make sure you are using XSLT version 2.0, as the replace function is only available in XSLT version 2.0, not in version 1.0

Answer (score 0):

First your given link is not working ,

> http://mycompany.com?mypage=xyz&version=999.

I think simply you want to transform your xml into html in java.

for that visit this discussion.
[suggestions-for-a-java-based-templating-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174204/suggestions-for-a-java-based-templating-engine)

This is done by template engine, widely used template engines in java are Freemarker and velocity. others are also available.

Here is list of Java Template Engines.
[Java Template Engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_engine_%28web%29)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write the & characters in the URL as it is instead of &amp; use disable output escaping. Use concat function to append anything else you want to the url.

```
<xsl:value-of select="$url" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```